# Android trigger a service every time a photo is taken from camera

Tags: android, service, camera

I need to trigger a service every time a photo is taken from camera (from any application like facebook, sketchup... or user explicitly
takes photo from camera using the build in Camera application). How we can achive this? I searched around the internet I found nothing 
similar to this.
Any suggestion should be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a broadcast reciever to the camera button. 
Something like this in your manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".pictureReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10000" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```